# Importing a existing website to wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

Hi i want to import an existing website into a blank `wordpress`. Do you guys have a idea how to do this without paying for it? The existing website uses an custom cms. And i've downloaded it with [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/page/2/). So i've only static content.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You can, of course, do this yourself and avoid the need to pay anyone anything to do it for you. Sadly though the short answer is that there is no easy way to make this happen. To simplify it as best as I can you need to crawl the pages with static content, parse out whatever you deem to be the main content of those pages and import them into the posts table of a WordPress database - attaching the relevant metadata. It's a fairly complicated project and most definitely best handled by someone who's done it before.

Comment: is it possible to make a theme of an existing website? I transferred all the content but need the right style. I know there are websites to see wich theme comes close to your website but i have to pay for them....

Comment: Yes that's possible, you just need to turn the html design into WordPress theme template files. These articles go into detail of how that's done: http://code.tutsplus.com/series/creating-a-wordpress-theme-from-static-html--wp-34294 I've refered people to them before and had feedback that they were easy enough to understand for anyone with html and css plus a little php knowledge.

Comment: I've never used it before but you could also give this a try to build the theme for you http://www.themematcher.com/